# count specific characters in a string (Java)

Tags: java, string, char, histogram

I have a homework assignment to count specific chars in string.

For example: `string = "America"`

The output should be = `a appear 2 times, m appear 1 time, e appear 1 time, r appear 1 time, i appear 1 time and c appear 1 time`

```
public class switchbobo {

/**
 * @param args
 */     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "BUNANA";
    String lower = s.toLowerCase();
    char[] c = lower.toCharArray(); // converting to a char array
    int freq =0, freq2 = 0,freq3 = 0,freq4=0,freq5 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< c.length;i++) {
        if(c[i]=='a') // looking for 'a' only
          freq++;
        if(c[i]=='b')
          freq2++;
        if (c[i]=='c') {
          freq3++;
        }

        if (c[i]=='d') {
          freq4++;
        }       
    }
    System.out.println("Total chars "+c.length);
    if (freq > 0) {
      System.out.println("Number of 'a' are "+freq);
    }
  }
}
```

code above is what I have done, but I think it is not make sense to have 26 variables (one for each letter). Do you guys have alternative result?

Comment: Use an array with 26 indices. (`'a'-'a' == 0, 'b' - 'a' == 1`, so on and so forth).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously your intuition of having a variable for each letter is correct.

The problem is that you don't have any automated way to do the same work on different variables, you don't have any trivial syntax which helps you doing the same work (counting a single char frequency) for 26 different variables.

So what could you do? I'll hint you toward two solutions:

- you can use an array (but you will have to find a way to map character `a-z` to indices `0-25`, which is somehow trivial is you reason about ASCII encoding)
- you can use a [`HashMap<Character, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which is an associative container that, in this situation, allows you to have numbers mapped to specific characters so it perfectly fits your needs

Comment: With Guava one could also use a [`Multiset<Character>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) but that's probably overkill for homework :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `HashMap` of Character key and Integer value.

```
HashMap<Character,Integer>
```

iterate through the string

```
-if the character exists in the map get the Integer value and increment it.
-if not then insert it to map and set the integer value for 0
```

This is a pseudo code and you have to try coding it

Answer (score 2):

I am using a HashMap for the solution.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sample2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    String test = "BUNANA";
    char[] chars = test.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<chars.length;i++)
    {
        if(!map.containsKey(chars[i]))
        {
            map.put(chars[i], 1);
        }
        map.put(chars[i], map.get(chars[i])+1);
    }

    System.out.println(map.toString());
 }

}
```

Produced Output -
    {U=2, A=3, B=2, N=3}

Comment: have you tried it? because it gives +1 for each letter

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to Jack's answer the following code could be your solution. It uses the an array to store the frequency of characters.

```
public class SwitchBobo 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String s = "BUNANA";
      String lower = s.toLowerCase();
      char[] c = lower.toCharArray();
      int[] freq = new int[26];
      for(int i = 0; i< c.length;i++) 
      {
         if(c[i] <= 122)
         {
            if(c[i] >= 97)
            {
               freq[(c[i]-97)]++;
            }
         }        
      }
      System.out.println("Total chars " + c.length);
      for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
      {
         if(freq[i] != 0)   
            System.out.println(((char)(i+97)) + "\t" + freq[i]);
      }      
   }
}
```

It will give the following output:

```
Total chars 6
a       2
b       1
n       2
u       1
```

Comment: About code c[i]-97, would that work as expected? It's a suspect for me since variable c is char type, and it's subtracting an integer. In C language, you can make it work but Java is a much stricter typing language. Hence I do not encourage it.  Using ASCII encoding is safer and more conventional. For example, what is the ASCII value of letter 'a'?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid: yes it would. i wouldn't have posted it if it didn't. `When an arithmetic operation is performed between a character and an integer, it is actually performed between the ascii value of the character and the integer. The result of such operation is also an integer.` The ascii value of 'a' is 97!!

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[]=new int[26];//default with count as 0
for each chars at string
if (String having uppercase)
  a[chars-'A' ]++
if lowercase 
then a[chars-'a']++
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestCharCount {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "america";
        int len = s.length();
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        int ct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ct = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                if (c[i] == ' ')
                    break;
                if (c[i] == c[j]) {
                    ct++;
                    c[j] = ' ';
                }

            }
            if (c[i] != ' ')
                System.out.println("number of occurance(s) of " + c[i] + ":"
                        + ct);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, it helps if you provide some explanation to go along with your code. this way rather than copy/paste and hope it works, the person asking the question will be able to see why something works, and why there's didn't

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this

```
public static int CountInstanceOfChar(String text, char character   ) {
    char[] listOfChars = text.toCharArray();
    int total = 0 ;
    for(int charIndex = 0 ; charIndex < listOfChars.length ; charIndex++)
        if(listOfChars[charIndex] == character)
            total++;
    return total;
}
```

for example:

```
String text = "america";
char charToFind = 'a';
System.out.println(charToFind +" appear " + CountInstanceOfChar(text,charToFind) +" times");
```

Answer (score 0):

Count char 'l' in the string.

```
  String test = "Hello";
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<test.length();i++){
   if(test.charAt(i)== 'l'){
       count++;
        }
    }
```

or

```
int count=  StringUtils.countMatches("Hello", "l");
```